# Garbage Collection in case of dynamic object

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

```
Foo a;

try
{
 // some work with a;
}
finally
{
 a = null;
}
```

In this example, we mark object a for garbage collection.

Now suppose, we modify the code like this.

```
public  xyz()
{
 return new Foo();
}
```

Now in this example, the newly created object has no name, so when will it be marked for collection ? Or GC will automatically determine that it has no use, so it will try to recover it ?

EDIT :

After reading the answer, I am adding one more situation.

```
Foo a;

try
{     
  return a;
}
finally
{
 a = null;
}
```

Now what will happen ?

Comment: what is the return type of `xyz()`, btw? 'cos `public xyz() { return new Foo(); }` is never valid...

Comment: @MarcGravell - Well if the type matters, I want to find that too since I didnt knew that type do matters in garbage collection.

Comment: the return type doesn't matter, if `xyz` is a class - it is still an object no matter what you *call* it. If `xyz` is a struct, then returning `object`/`dynamic`/an-interface will introduce *boxing*, so will **add** an object that needs collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the caller of xyz assigns the result to something, then it will stick around, otherwise it will be GC'd eventually. Just need something to hold on to a reference for the object to survive GC.

Comment: I guess I have cleared my confusion. Unless the object is not hooked on to something, it will be collected as some later point. Right ?

Answer (score 4):

It is **never** "marked for garbage collection"... it is an object and exists - *that is sufficient* for GC to consider it. Assigning to fields and variables just impacts when it can be *successfully* collected.

In regard to the second example:

- if it is on the stack as a value (as the return from `xyz()`) it won't be collected
- if it is held in a local variable, it won't be collected (maybe depending on whether that variable is ever *read* again, depending on the GC implementation)
- if it is held somewhere as a field on a reachable (non-collectable) object, it won't be collected

Answer (score 2):

> In this example, we mark object a for garbage collection.

No, you don't. Unless you use the variable later in the code, the garbage collector already knows that the reference isn't used any more. It can collect the object after the last use, so the object might even be collected *before* you set the reference to null.

Setting the reference to null have no effect at all as far as the garbage collector is concerned, unless you use the variable later in the code.

```
Foo a = new A();

try {
  // some work with a;
  // at this point a is no longer used, so it can be collected
} finally {
  // this has no effect on garbage collection:
  a = null;
}
```

You don't need to do anything at all to objects to make them collectible, you just stop using them, and they will be collected.

The only objects that need special treatment is the ones that implement the `IDisposable` interface. You should call the `Dispose` method on those objects when you are done with them, or put them in a `using` block, which will call `Dispose` automatically.

#### Edit:

In your added scenario where you set the variable to null, that also has no effect on the garbage collection. You are setting the local variable to null, which has no effect on the object reference that you have already handed over to be returned.

Comment: **The only objects that need special treatment is the ones that implement the IDisposable interface. You should call the Dispose method on those objects when you are done with them, or put them in a using block, which will call Dispose automatically.** Learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting [article in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t81zye4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) about C# Object Lifetime.

A snippet:

> the garbage collector traces object references and identifies objects
>   that can no longer be accessed by running code

It does explicitly say it's not using reference counting, but an alternative where it scans if objects have any accessibly references. If the code cannot access an object, it's marked for collection.

Comment: So in a large code, it traces all objects ? Will not that hit performance issues ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx -- Here are some more reading materials on the subject. I do know that the compiler uses "Generations" to determine the age of an object and help decide how often that object needs to be tested for references.

Comment: @harrisunderwork GC on the main .NET CLR uses a "generational" approach, which is pretty efficient, *especially* for short-lived objects (i.e. the majority)

Answer (score 0):

when you write `Foo a;` you are creating only a memory to reference to an object of type `Foo` on stack.

when you write `new Foo();`, then you are creating only an object of type `Foo` on Heap with no reference.

and when you write `Foo a = new Foo();` then you are making `a` to refer to object `Foo` on Heap as shown

[image]

when you set `a = null;`, you are just removing the reference to the object `Foo` on Heap and is no more referenced.

GC will collect any such objects which are no more referenced.

its same when you create an object inside a method and return from the method.
The reference you create like `a` inside the method will be cleared from stack when you return,  and the object you created inside method is no longer referenced(unless reference is returned). GC collects it.

Comment: Yup, I understood that. As long as an object is sticked to any reference, it will not be collected.